# BB10 : How to change the phone profile in BB 10 using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I searched a lot but did not find the answer, whether it is possible to change the phone profile programmatically in BB OS 10 using HTML5/Java Script?

My requirement is when user receives a call the phone must get silent or device volume changed to lowest or profile changed to mute.

If it is possible in Native BlackBerry using C/C++?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can not be done directly through the WebWorks SDK. I don't see any plugins for it in the [community APIs in Github](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova).

It looks like it **can** be done natively though, so you could potentially write a Cordova plugin to expose it in Javascript. The [BlackBerry 10 Cordova Plugin Template](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova/Template) may be helpful! Note that there's a new permission element that you'll need in order to change it the setting.

More info: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__notificationglobalsettings.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Hanamj. Thanks for replying. I am new to BB10 so don't understand much what you gave. Seems like NotificationGloabalSetting setVolume can be used here but How I am not sure. Can you please explain it a little bit?